# How can I find part of a string between two words?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get a part of text from my field `description`

Could someone offer some advice?

The whole string is `'Version100][BuildNumber:666][SubBuild:000]'` and the build number is what I want to single out (however the number may change).

I have tried `SUBSTRING` with `CHARINDEX` but I can't seem to figure it out.

I've been googling for about 30 minutes and I can't seem to work it out.

Comment: Can you share what you tried?

Comment: is the buildnumber always 3 digits?

Comment: You are using MS SQL Server? What version?

Comment: @vkp yes it is always 3digits but it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([description],CHARINDEX('BuildNumber:',[description])+12,
    CHARINDEX(']',[description], CHARINDEX('BuildNumber:',[description]))
    -(CHARINDEX('BuildNumber:',[description])+12))
FROM YOURTABLE
```

Comment: Thanks Roberto - perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

little long, but you could do this.

```
DECLARE @Description VARCHAR(MAX)= '[Version100][BuildNumber:666][SubBuild:000]'
SELECT  LEFT(STUFF(@Description, 1, PATINDEX('%BuildNumber%', @Description) + 11, '' )
            ,PATINDEX('%]%', STUFF(@Description, 1, PATINDEX('%BuildNumber%', @Description) + 11, '' )) - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @JamieD77 but this doesn't work as the build number can change (always 3 digits though).

Comment: @SCramphorn what does that mean it can change?

Comment: @SCramphorn do you mean the descriptions are in a table and you cant figure out how to change this into a `SELECT FROM` query?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this query can return your expected result with out hard-coding the build number count:

```
DECLARE @Description AS VARCHAR (500) = 'Version100][BuildNumber:6663211][SubBuild:000]';
DECLARE @BeforeString AS VARCHAR (100) = '[BuildNumber:';
DECLARE @BeforeStringPosition AS INT = CHARINDEX(@BeforeString, @Description);
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Description, @BeforeStringPosition + LEN(@BeforeString) , CHARINDEX('][SubBuild', @Description) - @BeforeStringPosition - LEN(@BeforeString));
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tested this (numeric offsets might be a bit off, but you can tweak them), but assuming the string formats are always the same, then the following should work, irrespective of the number of digits in the build number.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(description, 
                 CHARINDEX('BuildNumber', description) + 11, --The position after BuildNumber: (a)
                 CHARINDEX('][SubBuild', description) - 3 - CHARINDEX('BuildNumber', description) + 11)) --The distance from (a) to the square brackets before SubBuild
```